# Python: MiniMax Algorithm for Checkers/Draughts, King stuck in a loop bug

Tags: python, algorithm, minimax

So I have been doing this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYbrH1Cl3nw&lc=Ugy5CzafDyMADcUcQ_54AaABAg) and it works (almost) fine, however the AI King gets stuck in the corner and repeats same moves (unless it is able to caputure). You can see the same problem in the provided video. My implementation is like in the tutorial, but with alpha beta pruning optimization.

So I think the implementation of the minimax might have a bug:

```
def minimax(position, depth, alpha, beta, to_max, game):
        if depth == 0 or position.winner() is not None:
        return position.evaluate(), position
    if to_max:
        maxEval = float('-inf')
        best_move = None
        for move in get_all_moves(position, AI_COLOR, game):
            eval = minimax(move, depth - 1, alpha, beta, False, game)[0]
            maxEval = max(maxEval, eval)
            alpha = max(alpha, eval)
            if maxEval == eval:
                print("moved: ")
                print(maxEval)
                best_move = move
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        print("estimated: ")
        print(maxEval)
        return maxEval, best_move
    else:
        minEval = float('inf')
        best_move = None
        for move in get_all_moves(position, PLAYER_COLOR, game):
            eval = minimax(move, depth - 1, alpha, beta, True, game)[0]
            minEval = min(minEval, eval)
            beta = min(beta, eval)
            if minEval == eval:
                best_move = move
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return minEval, best_move
```

My guess is that this part is wrong:

```
if maxEval == eval:
   best_move = move
```

You can find the full code of the tutorial [here](https://github.com/techwithtim/Python-Checkers-AI)

Is my assumption right? What could I do to debug this?

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be anything obviously wrong with the implementation of alpha-beta or minimax in this code. Did you test the evaluation function, move generation, and the minimax function without alpha-beta?

Comment: @kcsquared the evaluation is basically a one line returning the difference of left pawns and kings between players. MiniMax had the same issue even without alpha beta pruning. Searching for the valid moves actually works fine, because I am able to play with my king as I wish. I suspect the minimax algorithm either won't return the best move it calculated or it terminates too early without considering every figure on the board

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, maybe it's related to the position, like in the video (at 38:10) where it seems like white pieces can't move ; try to run the code for more depths to see how the AI responds.

Comment: @Vintarel no it does it even if it has better moves like capturing or trying to get new kings. It also tends to use the same pawn until there are no possible moves for it and only then switches to others

Comment: When AI makes the same moves all the time it is because it doesn't find a better move. So basically there is either something wrong with how you evaluate the position or how you decide the best move in minimax algorithm.